# Why does charging my phone from my PC cause keyboard and mouse problems

Tags: usb, windows-11, mobile-phone

I charge my phone (a OnePlus 7T) by plugging it into a USB 3 port on my PC and laptop, and this work fine. It's a slow charge but since I'm at my PC for hours it still fully charges the phone.

Anyhow, I've begun to notice that when the phone is charging I get occasional odd behaviour from my USB wireless keyboard and mouse. Occasionally while I'm typing the keyboard will pause for a moment then I'll get several repeats of the last character I typed. With the mouse I get occasional double clicks when I only pressed the mouse button once. This doesn't happen often, but it happens often enough that I can be certain it only happens when the phone is connected to my PC.

I think this might have started at about the time I switched to Windows 11. I can't be certain about this, but I've been charging my phone from the PC for years and I don't recall it happening for the several years I used Windows 10.

Other info: it happens on both my PC (Dell Optiplex 3000 micro) and laptop (LG Gram 16Z90P). The wireless keyboard is a Dell KM632 and the mouse is a KM636. Although these are both Dell branded they are from different manufacturers and use different wireless dongles.

I also use different (reputable) makes of USB cable on the PC and laptop, so the phone is the only common element. I haven't tried a different make of phone since I only have the one phone. It happens even when the phone is fully charged and shouldn't be drawing much power so I don't think it can be a power draw problem.

Can anyone suggest what could be causing this and how to fix it? Other than of course not connecting my phone!

Comment: Have you tried different cables? USB 3 operates at higher speeds and I've heard of some cases where it interferes with other electronics, especially those using the 2.4GHz bands. A poorly shielded cable might be causing interference.

Comment: @Mokubai Good point, yes I do use different USB cables and they are reputable ones. JuicEBitz  in one case and erm I don't remember the brand used on my laptop but they weren't el cheapo cables.

Comment: It could just be that the USB power supplies are starting to have problems with age then. Phones will draw everything they can out of a port and if the port is not adequately limited (a PC port should be limited to 5V @ 500mA for USB2 and 900mA for USB 3 iirc. The power supply browning out slightly might cause your issues. Modern phones prefer higher powered supplies and will never charge at full speed from a PC USB port, most modern phones will charge at 9V 2A from their dedicated power bricks.

Comment: That's certainly possible. I'll have  look around and see if I can find a USB power meter to see exactly what the phone is drawing.

Comment: reputable things do not always work. "reputable" means nothing in this context.